# rmarkdown parameters conditional on another parameter value?

Tags: r-markdown

I'm creating a parametized report using rmarkdown with two selection boxes. I would like the values in the second selection box to be conditional on the value selected in the first selection box. Is this possible? If so, how?

Assuming that test.csv is a simple dataset where the first column is a key and the next columns are different lookup values for each key, here's is example code that demonstrates what I would like to be able to do. The first selectionbox is used to select the look-up column, and with the second selection box I would like to select values from the selected column:

````
---
params:
  areagroup: 
    label: "Area group:"
    value: wards
    input: select
    choices: !r x <- read.csv("test.csv"); names(x)
  selected area:
    label: "Selected area:"
    value: 1
    input: select
    choices: !r x <- read.csv("test.csv"); this_col <- which(names(x) == params$areagroup); x[, this_col]

---

```{r}

print(params$`areagroup`)
print(params$`selected area`)

```
````